# mysql memory highest and biz error log: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, hyperlink

At biz code (java) sometimes will appear error(below code):
and mysql server memory was highest,mysql slowlog not show some helpful information,How should I do that can troubleshoot this problem?
tks.

> java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3011)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3469)
>       ... 86 common frames omitted
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   The last packet successfully received from the server was 81,184 milliseconds ago.  
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 81,184 milliseconds ago.**

Comment: 'Connection was unexpectedly lost'. Is the network stable?

Comment: I am also confuse that is network problem ,but that server is have network traffic at that time, how can I locate it's network problem?

Comment: Maybe run a long ping command from client machine to server machine, dump output somewhere. When you again see a similar failure try to correlate with ping output. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I will try it ,tks